# Create stack of array from existing array

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$mail[0] = "test1@gmail.com";
$mail[1] = "test2@gmail.com";
$mail[2] = "test3@gmail.com";
$mail[3] = "test4@gmail.com";
$mail[4] = "test5@gmail.com";
$mail[5] = "test6@gmail.com";
```

Now I want to convert these mails to string and put them in array after every 3 mail of $mail separated by a comma.
Something like this -

```
$email[0] = "test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com";
$email[1] = "test4@gmail.com, test5@gmail.com, test6@gmail.com";
$email[2] = "test71@gmail.com, test8@gmail.com, test9@gmail.com";
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `array_chunk` + `implode`

Comment: Please provide what solutions you've attempted in your question. StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. We expect that question askers have attempted to solve their problems independently first. With that in mind, if you're new to programming then I highly recommend you look into using `loops` and `if statements` to achieve what you're looking for. You might also find the `modulo` operator (`%`) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight modification of your code:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($oneusers); $i+=3){
    $new[] = $oneusers[$i].", ".$oneusers[$i + 1].", ".$oneusers[$i + 2];
}

print_r($new);
```

Going further you can add additional check whether `$oneusers[key]` exists.

Another code, which will do the same but without writing `i, i+1, i+2`:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($oneusers, 3);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $new[] = implode(',', $chunk);
}

print_r($new);
```